# Obtain only one response from Xquery fetching elements in XML

Tags: xml, xquery, osb

I want to look for a specific node in a Response XML, and return true or false, depending on if it matches a condition. How can I do it in order to only receive a unique node response and not as many as elements the XML contains?

Here is my Xquery code:

```
for $recordRetrieved in $sA_ADS_VerifOutput1/ns0:recordRetrieved
        return
          if ($recordRetrieved/ns0:COD_NRBE_EN = $ent and
              $recordRetrieved/ns0:DAT <= $dat)
          then <ns2:func>{ true() }</ns2:func>
          else <ns2:func>{ false() }</ns2:func
```

with this code, if the XML contains 3 elements `$sA_ADS_VerifOutput1/ns0:recordRetrieved` the response will be (for instance):

```
<ns2:func>false</ns2:func>
<ns2:func>false</ns2:func>
<ns2:func>true</ns2:func>
```

I don't want this, but if all are false, I expect `<ns2:func>false</ns2:func>` and if at least one is true I expect `<ns2:func>true</ns2:func>`, only one time.

I thought about using the `where` clause, but I need to emerge false if no elemet meets the condition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
some $recordRetrieved in $sA_ADS_VerifOutput1/ns0:recordRetrieved
   satisfies ($recordRetrieved/ns0:COD_NRBE_EN = $ent and
              $recordRetrieved/ns0:DAT <= $dat)
```

or more simply

```
exists($sA_ADS_VerifOutput1/ns0:recordRetrieved[
        ns0:COD_NRBE_EN = $ent and ns0:DAT <= $dat])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awsome.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fn:distinct-values() to eliminate duplicates, then wrap them in the needed elements.

```
fn:distinct-values(
    for $recordRetrieved in $sA_ADS_VerifOutput1/ns0:recordRetrieved
    return
        if ($recordRetrieved/ns0:COD_NRBE_EN = $ent and
            $recordRetrieved/ns0:DAT <= $dat)
        then true()
        else false()
) ! <ns2:func>{.}</ns2:func>
```